# Get information of user with Twitter Oauth API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I need one twitter button on the registration form / page.

Registration page contains Firstname, Lastname, email.

When user click on Twitter button it should call twitter api, and open twitter login modal for credentials.
After filling details successfully, all the fields should auto populate with users information i.e. Firstname,Lastname ,email.
**I want all things with the help of the Jquery/javascript.**

I have created one application in twitter & I have Consumer Key (API Key),Consumer Secret (API Secret),Access Token & Access Token Secret.

I have tried below code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#target" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: setHeader,
        url: "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        scriptCharset: "utf-8",
        success: function(data) { alert('hello!'); console.log(data);},
        error: function(html) { alert(html); },

    });
    });
        });
     function setHeader(xhr) {
        if(xhr && xhr.overrideMimeType) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
        }


        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXX", oauth_nonce="XXXXXXXXXX", oauth_signature="XXXXXXX", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp= "XXXXXX", oauth_token, "XXXXXXXX", oauth_version="1.0"');
    }
```

It's giving an error like below:
"NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?callback=jQuery32103570901858061123_1499861152234&_=1499861152235"

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is your problem? This kind of sounds like you want someone to do it all for you and I don't think that's going to happen.

Comment: @vis5ion I have updated the code.

Comment: Content-Type for this request should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded (not application/j-son). Additionally, this endpoint does not have any documented support for jsonp callbacks according to https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials so ?callback=jQuery32103570901858061123_1499861152234&_=1499861152235 should be unrecognised by the API.